# How does the new Java 9 Platform Module System integrate into Maven?

Tags: java, maven, java-platform-module-system

I have recently looked at the new [Java Platform Module System](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/whatsnew/) which provides functionality that seems to overlap with what Maven offers in terms of dependency management between jar files. I was wondering how this new Java feature will affect Maven and if it has already been integrated into Maven or a similar tool, and if so, what would be a hello-world usage example.

Cheers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You seemed to misundestand the module system. Maven offers a dependency management system. The module system offers a system to define modules and the exported/required interfaces of modules...(something like OSGi without the dynamic part of OSGi)...Apart from that you can compile modules usign a `module-info.java` file for a longer time.

http://blog.soebes.de/blog/2017/06/06/howto-create-a-java-run-time-image-with-maven/
https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/module-info.html
https://www.slideshare.net/RobertScholte/java-9-and-the-impact-on-maven-projects
http://blog.joda.org/2017/04/java-se-9-jpms-modules-are-not-artifacts.html